Can I differentiate between ErrorMessage and diplayed error text in Razor pages
I'm coming from a Web Forms background and attempting to learn Razor pages. In Web Forms, I use the asp:Validation controls pretty extensively. These validation controls give me the option to specify an error message that will be displayed in the validation summary, and text that can be displayed where the control is in the code (right after the field). So, usually I will set a detailed error message (for the summary) and just a * for the text (for next to the offending field). This highlights the field needing attention but relegates long messages (that might throw off formatting near the field) to the validation summary. Here is sample code I might use to do that:
<asp:TextBox ID="txtTitle" runat="server" />
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfbTitleRequired" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Title is required." 
    Text="*" ControlToValidate="txtTitle" Display="Static" />

Is there an equivalent way to do this in Razor pages? I have a data model, and I'm using DataAnnotations to specify the validations needed for the field. The field is being validated correctly, displaying the error message information in the validation summary, however it ALSO puts the error message next to the field. I'd much rather have this display a * than the full text of the error. Is there a built-in way to have Razor pages do this, similar to the Validation controls in Web Forms? Here is my sample code from Razor:
In the csthml file I define the input field, a validation span after the input field, and a validation summary at the end of the form:
<div>
    <label asp-for="Phone">Phone:</label>
    <input asp-for="Phone" />
    <span asp-validation-for="Phone" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
<div asp-validation-summary="All" class="text-danger">Please correct the following errors:</div>

Then in the definition class for my data model I have the following for this property:
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Phone is required."), RegularExpression("^(1?(-?\\d{3})-?)?(\\d{3})(-?\\d{4})$", ErrorMessage = "Invalid format for phone.")]
public string Phone { get; set; }

I'm just wondering if there is a way to dynamically display a * after the offending field if, and only if, it fails validation, or would it take considerable outside coding?

**Thanks to the post here for leading me to develop the code for this solution as well as  MS Learning for starting me down the CSS portion.
It doesn't seem that it can be done automatically in the same way as Web Forms Validation controls do, but if you utilize the built-in CSS classes and make some changes to the HTML it CAN be done.
First, create a div for your summary information. Rather than using the asp-validation-summary helper, move all your asp-validation-for elements into this new div summary section. Give it a CSS class of clientside-validation-summary (so we can target it with our own styling). Next, put each input you're validating inside a span. It'll look something like this:
<div>
    <label asp-for="Phone">Phone:</label>
    <span><input asp-for="Phone" /></span>
</div>
<div class="form-group clientside-validation-summary">
    <span asp-validation-for=".Phone" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>

Next create some CSS:
.clientside-validation-summary{
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column nowrap;

    span.field-validation-error::before {
        content: "*";
        padding-right: .3rem;
    }
}
span:has(> input.input-validation-error)::after{ 
    content: "*";
    padding-left: .3rem;
    color: red;
}

The clientside-validation-summary class will format our "summary" section and add bullets to our error list.
The span:has section will target any span element that has an input that has the input-validation-error class (applied by the system). This will add a * after the span. We can't target the input element directly because it isn't considered a container element and therefore doesn't support psuedo elements such as ::after.
Because we've moved our asp-validation-for elements down and put them all together, we get what looks like a summary, and we've targeted our inputs so we also get the * after each invalid field.
